# How to display the current subdomain URL in a Rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Rails 4 and Devise. How could I, in devise/sessions/new.html.erb, display the full current URL, e.g. http://(request.subdomain).example.com, in the view?

For example in new.html.erb:

```
<p>Please bookmark http://yoursubdomain.example.com</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like that:-

```
request.original_url
```

In view as:-

```
<%= request.original_url %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Please bookmark <%= "http://" + request.subdomain + ".example.com" %></p>
```

Hope this helps.